# How to make button flashing after pressed?

Tags: java, android

i want make Mediaplayer buttons which start flashing after pressed, and stop flashing until i press the next Mediaplayer button, which also start flashing. I've got buttons now flash when pressed but the problem now is that how can I get them to stop flashing when I press the next button. Now the buttons continue to flash when I press the next button.

Here is my code i use now:

```
        mButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        mAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        mAnimation.setDuration(500);
        mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

        mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mButton2.clearAnimation();
                mButton1.startAnimation(mAnimation);

                {
                    mp.release();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Activity2.this, R.raw.audio_1);
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                    mp.start();


                }
                }
        });

        mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mButton1.clearAnimation();
                mButton2.startAnimation(mAnimation);

                {
                mp.release();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Activity2.this, R.raw.audio_2);
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();


            }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you explain this little more. Do you want to flash only one button from set of buttons? When pressed one button it starts flashing and previously flashing button should stop?

Comment: I have Mediaplayer with 12 differend Buttons/audio and I want the buttons to flash one at a time, depending on which button I press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach

```
mButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
mButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

mAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
mAnimation.setDuration(500);
mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

mBbutton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mButton2.clearAnimation();
        mButton1.startAnimation(mAnimation);
    }
});

mBbutton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mButton1.clearAnimation();
        mButton2.startAnimation(mAnimation);
    }
});
```

Note that on button1 click listener you should start animation in button1 and clear the animations of button2 and vice versa

If you have lot of buttons try to store them in an array and perform the logic

```
mButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();

mClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //stop flashing all buttons
        for(Button button : mButtons) {
            button.clearAnimation();
        }
        //start animation on this button
        v.startAnimation(mAnimation);
    }
});

Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
//get as many as buttons

mButtons.add(button1);
mButtons.add(button2);
//add all the buttons to array
```

Comment: Thanks for help, if you look my code now with 3 different buttons/audio now. How should I start building it up. I have try but i get lots of errors..

Comment: Hi, I finally get buttons flashing correctly but now I can not hear the audio file. Can you pls tell me what i do wrong. check my code i edited?

Comment: Code to run the audio playback is not called in the button click listener. Add the code to run audio after the startAnimation() method in each click listener. This is the piece of code in your btn1() and btn2() methods

Comment: YES!! Now its working! Thank you very much.. edit the code how is now.. :)